# How to get integral type from a template type array

Tags: c++, templates, smart-pointers

Im trying to write a scoped pointer class which calls delete once it is destroyed. I realized that i would need to check whether my pointer is pointing to an array or not, so i could call the right delete.
Taking inspiration from std::unique_ptr i used type_traits to check if the template argument, which holds the type pointer, is an array or not:

```cpp
template <typename type, bool _Dx = std::is_array<type>::value>
    class scoped_ptr {
    private:
        type* m_ptr;
    //...
    };

template <typename type>
    class scoped_ptr<type, true> {};
```

But if my template argument type is "int[]" the codes invalidates because i cant have an "int[]* m_ptr"
How can i solve this problem? How can i pass int[] argument and have "int* m_ptr"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [`std::remove_extent`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_extent).  If you give it an array it gives you the element type, otherwise it just gives you the type you gave it.  That would look like

```
template <typename type, bool _Dx = std::is_array<type>::value>
class scoped_ptr {
private:
    std::remove_extent_t<type>* m_ptr;
//...
};
```

---

Also note that `_Dx` is an illegal name.  All names that start with an underscore and are followed with a capital letter are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Wow thanks, that was really helpfull, can i alias that type with a using/typedef?

Comment: @Denomycor Yep.  You can do `using BaseType = std::conditional_t<_Dx, std::remove_extent_t<type>, type>; ...; BaseType* m_ptr`

Comment: @Denomycor Please note that I have updated my answer.  The `std::conditional_t` was not needed.